# STM32L452 not entering boot loader until power cycle

Tags: stm32, cortex-m4

I have an application which upon command erases the first page and issues a reset by writing 0x05FA0004 to AIRCR. I expected it to restart and end up in the native boot loader, but it doesn't until I cycle the power. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you wait for the erase to be complete before executing the reset in software? Do you happen to erase the page you are currently executing from, so it can't fetch any opcodes after erase is in progress?

Comment: I do wait for BSY flag to clear. Also, I have turned interrupts off and made sure I am not executing in the page being erased.

Comment: Why erase the first page and reset, rather than jumping directly into the bootloader? Do you have any activity on the important relevant interfaces? (see [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2606-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf), page 324). The ROM bootloader will check if the first address of Bank2 is in SRAM (if so jump+run), otherwise if Bank1 is in SRAM (if so jump+run), otherwise continue with the bootloader (see AN2606, page 328). Have you confirmed that these tests hold true? (e.g: by dumping the flash)

Comment: Have you investigated the value in `SYSCFG_MEMRMP.MEM_MODE`? It looks like this should be re-evaluated on reset (including via `AIRCR.SYSRESETREQ`), but it would be worth confirming. "_... latched on the 4th edge of the internal startup clock source after reset release._"

Comment: going into the factory boot loader implies reprogramming?  Once in the factory boot loader you are connecting to the device externally to program anyway, what is wrong with boot0 plus a reset and no worries about if the application was working and if it was able to erase, etc?

Comment: "Up to 512 KB single bank Flash"  You are executing the flash erase code from sram yes?  Not running that code in flash?

Comment: Are you erasing both flash banks used for booting, not just one of them? Did you check that FLASH_OPTR register is correctly set to decide from where to boot?

Comment: The STM32L452CC has only one Flash bank. (I am gonna check FLASH_OPTR, but since it does end up in the bootloader after POR I just assumed it was correct). 

The difference between power cycle reset and "sw" reset is that RAM memory is retained. I wonder if i-cache could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to plan on the FLASH "empty" flag to enter the bootloader. However, the FLASH "empty" check is performed only upon power-on reset and OBL_LAUNCH, see description of FLASH_SR.PEMPTY bit in Flash chapter of RM0394. It means, it is not performed upon software reset (or "pushbutton" or watchdog reset).

Perform OBL_LAUNCH instead of the software reset.

(This issue is usually brought up in the other way round, i.e. that program does not run properly if poweron was performed with "empty" FLASH and after programming there was only a software or pushbutton reset.)

Comment: I disabled the d and i caches and erased the first flash page. The next instruction reads adress 0x0800000 as 0xffffffff. Next, I set the obl_launch bit in flash->cr. Nothing happens. It just continues to the next instruction. The PEMPTY bit in flash->sr is still 0. If I enable the WWDG it behaves like before, i.e., requires a power cycle to work again. The PEMPTY is "settable". What does setting it mean? I have not tried that yet.

Comment: _Next, I set the obl_launch bit in flash->cr._ Do you unlock OPTLOCK before that, as the description of OBL_LAUNCH bit requires?

Comment: That did it. 

Upon command:
1. Disable interrupts
2. Unlock Flash->cr, using Flash->keyr 
3. Erase first Flash page
4. Wait for Flash->sr (BSY) to clear
5. Unlock option bits is Flash->cr, using Flash->optkeyr
6. Issue OBL_LAUNCH (i.e., set bit(27) in Flash->cr

The processor reboots and I can connect to the native bootloader.